# How to use a DLL in c++

Tags: c++, dll

I need to write a c++ program using an DLL. I have the DLL and a header file, but no .a file for the linker. The GNU GCC Compiler cannot find the functions in the DLL file.

I’m getting errors like:

```
    undefined reference to _imp__mbnEthernetOpen@8
```

How do I fix this problem.

Comment: Was the function exported?

Comment: Do you have the .lib file (needed for implicit/statically linking to a .dll) ?

Comment: Dynamic linking in Windows requires some .lib files to be located in library path. Do you have any shipped with the DLL you are using?

Comment: What platform are you developing on?  a .a sounds like Linux but a .dll would be on Windows and a .so used on Linux.  Decide if you want a dynamic or static library and state the platform and it would be easy to tell you the command to use.

Comment: The DLL and Header ere supplied, they don’t have a .lib or .a file.

Comment: I am working under windows.

Comment: @diegoperini dynamic linking does not _require_ to have .lib.

Comment: Is mbnEthernetOpen declared in the headers ? Did you include the headers ? What is the declaration for mbnEthernetOpen in the headers ? I don't know about gcc in Windows, but in Visual Studio the declaration for mbnEthernetOpen would tipically be something like "type __declspec(dllexport) mbnEthernetOpen(" etc.

Comment: Also, from what I remember, if a lib file isn't provided you will need to create a small text file with extension .DEF describing the functions and the name of the dll to which they belong (google it, one of the first hits is to the MSDN page about .DEF files).

Comment: You can create a .lib file. The GCC toolset has tools to do that.

Comment: Ops, in my comment above, the likely declaration for a function imported from a dll would be "type __declspec(dllimport) mbnEthernetOpen(" etc, and no "export".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to compile a program that depends on another shared library. To compile in support for this library on windows you typically need 3 things:

- header file
- lib binary for compile time linking
- dll binary used for runtime execution (must be in path of the binary
  to be found and loaded at runtime)  *OPTIONAL* if you are statically linking the .lib file

You are saying in your comments that all you have is the header and dll files. This means either you are missing the lib binary and need to find/recompile the library OR you're trying to dynamically load the DLL at runtime and use function pointers to call the different functions (as Goksel mentions in his answer).  Your error suggests that you're trying to do the first option (link to a shared library).

You need to have the lib file if you're going to be dynamically linking to the library at compile time.

Comment: I believe it's possible to do without a lib file by providing a def file. See my other comment above.

Comment: @JoséX. No, you got that wrong. The .def file is used when compiling the DLL.

Comment: @David Heffernan: please take a look here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54xsd65y.aspx

Comment: @JoséX. That article discusses importing data

Comment: @David Heffernan: Oh my, I did it again...it seems I remembered wrongly...I *did* use .def files a long time ago, but it seems it really is not possible to link to a dll using only a .def file. Sorry for the mess.

Answer (score 1):

It has been quite a long time since I last used WinAPI though if I recall correctly you need to dynamically load the library in runtime using either of [`LoadLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`LoadLibraryEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms684179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Afterwards you'd need to get the address of the specific function you are interested in using [`GetProcAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx); in your case this would be `mbnEthernetOpen` (I guess).

After all this hassle, you can finally call `mbnEthernetOpen` through the function pointer you have just obtained from the DLL.

**Edit:** After reading through the comments, I decided to extend my answer to contain a method for generating the `.lib` file.

First of all, [VLC](http://videolan.org)'s [wiki](http://wiki.videolan.org) has a very well written [article](http://wiki.videolan.org/GenerateLibFromDll) that goes through the process thoroughly. However, for the sake of clarity I'll repeat it here.

1. From the *Start* menu locate and execute *Visual Studio Command Prompt*, according to the wiki this should be under the *Microsoft Visual Studio* entry.
2. On the *Visual Studio Command Prompt* execute this command-line to extract the symbols from the DLL file: `dumpbin /exports input.dll > exports.def` Make sure you replace `input.dll` and `exports.def` with the paths to the correct input and output files, respectively.

   At this point you can fire up your text editor and edit your newly generated `.def` file to look something like this:

   ```
   EXPORTS
   libvlc_add_intf
   libvlc_audio_get_channel
   libvlc_audio_get_mute
   libvlc_audio_get_track
   libvlc_audio_get_track_count
   libvlc_audio_get_track_description
   libvlc_audio_get_volume
   …
   ```

   Obviously, the names of the exported symbols will be different for your DLL.

   However, for whatever reason if you wish not to do all of this manually, the cool guys who wrote the article on the VLC wiki came up with a one-shot command-line that does generate a `.def` file automatically:

   ```
   echo EXPORTS > output.def
   for /f "usebackq tokens=4,* delims=_ " %i in (`dumpbin /exports input.dll`) do if %i==tag echo %i_%j >> exports.def
   ```

   Again make sure you replace the temporary names with their corrected equivalents, additionally pay attention to that `tag` symbol. In VLC's example this was `libvlc`, it is the initial part of each exported symbol in their example. Now, since you have shown us a single function I am not sure what this should be, but I am sure you can figure it out by taking a look at the exported symbols.
3. And finally, generate the `.lib` file from these exported symbols which are now in your `.def` file:
   `lib /def:exports.def /out:library.lib /machine:x86`

   Beware that your `/machine` might be different depending on your platform.

There you go. This is how you generate a `.lib` file from a `.dll` file.

Comment: he said the compiler can't find the functions. LoadLibrary and things are used at runtime.

Comment: No, you generally don't need to use LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress. In the general (and usual) case you simply link in a "lib" file associated with the dll.

Comment: @JoséX. Except the OP said they don't *have* a `.lib`.

Comment: You want to avoid doing this if you can. Create the missing .lib file.

Comment: He would not be getting the stated error if he was trying to dynamically load a dll at runtime (specifically what `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` are used for). The error he is getting is a compile time error which typically means he's trying to link to a library. +1 @amrith

Comment: @g19fanatic So what? He would not be getting the error if he didn't try to call the function at all. That doesn't make that the solution. It is generally far easier to use load time linking than runtime linking.

Comment: @Angew: Yes, I jumped the gun. Sorry.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I wasn't +1 to this answer, but to amrith's initial comment that LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress are not the solution as I state in my included answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include instructions on how to generate a `.lib` from a `.dll`. I see that some other answer is already chosen as the correct answer, but hopefully this can still help others out there.